# How to read an integer written in exponential form with Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghci

To read an integer written in decimal form is quite simple :

```
Prelude> read "1000000000" :: Int
1000000000
```

But how to read an integer written in exponetial form ?

```
Prelude> read "10e+9" :: Int
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Is there a function in the `Prelude` to do that, or do we need to parse the expression?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Nothing in the `Prelude`, you need to write your own parser, I'm afraid.

Comment: Your example works for me (although it overflows) using ghc 7.0.4.

Comment: @dave4420 Doesn't work with ghc >= 7.4 anymore. It shouldn't have worked before that either, per the report, iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the exact format of the string, you could just `read` it into a floating point type:

```
> read "10e+9" :: Double
1.0e10
```

[then convert to an integral type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers#Converting_to_Integral) -- I'd recommend `Integer` instead of `Int`:

```
> floor (read "10e+9" :: Double) :: Integer
10000000000
```

Comment: `Prelude> floor 10e78 ==> 9999999999999999673560075006595519222746403606649979913266024618633003221909504`

Comment: @Will `ghci> 10e780`, `ghci> floor 10e780` gotta love floating-point numbers.

Comment: It does fail at reading "5.e-003", which some engineering software produce.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a parser

```
readI xs = let (m,e) = break (=='e') xs in 
     read m * 10 ^ case e of
       "" -> 1
       ('e':'+':p) -> read p
       ('e':p) -> read p
```

Giving

```
Main> readI "3e5"
300000
Main> readI "3e+500"
300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Main> readI "3e+500" :: Int
0
Main> readI "3e+500" :: Integer
300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And also

```
Main> readI "32e-5" 
Program error: Prelude.^: negative exponent
```

We could try to make it cope with negative exponents that give integer answers but that would be overkill for a read function.